# Regex space and special character selector

Tags: markdown, react-markdown

I'm using rich text editor. I convert `html` output to `markdown`. I have a problem like that;
If I type `**text**` it works. But if I type like that `**text **` (space after word) my app doesn't recognise markdown. So I want to select `space` and `*` or `space` and `_` with `regex`. I am going to remove `space` before `*` or `_` and put it after of the word.

Shortly I need this;

1. `**text **` -> `**text**`
2. `_text _` -> `_text_`
3. `*text *` -> `*text*`

and of course if you know how can I solve this problem with `react-markdown` its better for this problem.

I am using react with react-markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex engine supports look arounds:

```
Search: "(?<=\w) (?=[_*])"
Replace: ""
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/BYSr1P95iG6lRm).

`(?<=\w)` is a look behind that asserts the previous character is a word character.
`(?=[_*])` is a look ahead that asserts the following character is an underscore of asterisk.

If look arounds are not available, capture the surrounding characters then restore them:

```
Search: "(\w) ([_*])"
Replace: "$1$2"
```

---

In your comment you have changed the nature of the question to not *delete* the space, but the *interchange* the asterisk and the space, and only where the word has a balanced number of asterisks preceding it, then also *insert* a space where there isn't one. There is no general solution using regex for an arbitrary number of asterisks surrounding a word. However, if you limit the number to 2, this will work:

First repair double asterisks:

```
Search: "(\*\*\w+) \*\*"
Replace: "$1** "
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zGMNOno6vuGkZh).

Then the single asterisks:

```
Search: "(\*\*\w+) \*\*"
Replace: "$1** "
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/WyttPjM3vCk8XN).

Then fix the missing space involving 2 asterisks:

```
Search: "(?<!\*)(\*\*\w+)\*\*(?=\*)"
Replace: "$1** "
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/SOaTukNUNZEHIg).

Finally fix the missing spaces for single asterisks:

```
Search: "(?<!\*)(\*\w+)\*(?=\*)"
Replace: "$1* "
```

But even then you will probably find there are cases of input that will not give the desired result.

Your comment's more complicated requirements as best served by *parsing* the input byte by byte, and correcting it using a syntax model.

Comment: It is not working for like text : ```**Bold ***italic ***Bold***italic*```. It replaces like that: ```**Bold***italic***Bold***italic*```, but I need this: ```**Bold** *italic* **Bold** *italic*```. I am using second one.

Comment: @Abdul You are actually asking a different question in your comment than you asked in the question. Nevertheless, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
((\*{1,2}|_).*?)\s*\2
```

and the substitution string:

"`\1\2` "

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/OTnHRR/1)